# APK or bundles does not contain 64 bit native code

Tags: android-studio, apk, 64-bit, cocos2d-x, bundles

When I about to publish a game on play store console, I got an error stating that[image: erron on play console].

My project built by a third-party app builder that uses native libraries(cocos2dx).I tried to solve the issue as per [google developers](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit) but, could not solve the issue.
When I analyze the APK on Android studio, I got like this[image: Apk analyzer]

Help me to solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/critical-support-for-64bit-on-cocos2d-x-on-android/45516), you can set the following property in your gradle.properties file:

```
PROP_APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a:arm64-v8a
```

Comment: Even I did the same thing. But, still  error is there

Comment: What version of cocos2dx do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using cocos2d-x-3.16, build:gradle:3.2.1

Let's try my way:

1. In the toolbar, choose to Build -> Clean Project (2, 3 times)
2. Open file **proj.android-studio/gradle.properties** and check the configuration below:

   android.enableAapt2=true

   PROP_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION=28

   PROP_MIN_SDK_VERSION=14

   PROP_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=28

   PROP_APP_PLATFORM=19

   PROP_APP_ABI=arm64-v8a -> The 64bit-version
3. Open file **pro.android-studio/app/jni/Application.mk** and check the configuration below:

   APP_ABI := arm64-v8a

   APP_PLATFORM := android-19
4. In the toolbar, choose to Build -> Build Project

Good luck!